# How much heat can a speaker cables PVC jacket take?

Tags: cable, heat

Can a regular speaker cables PVC jacket survive 120°C atmosphere? Or do I have to use some other cable?

[image]

Comment: Maybe I could try to separate the whole cable, but I can't use the cable naked because the space where I am installing it is moist also:/ but I will still try to separate it from heat somehow.

Comment: well i would test it , i think it's a lot tho, have you thought of trying cloth wire? I've seen them getting some black burns from time to time but could work... especially if its a fat one!

Comment: This question seems better suited to electrical engineering stack exchange.

Answer (score 4):

### You have to use some other cable.

I usually go with Teflon in difficult thermal situations.

---

In general, the thermal performance of PVC *may be severely inadequate* for the 120°C conditions you've mentioned. Many forms of PVC insulation are rated as low as 80°C. Here are some supporting references to back up this claim:

See `Semi-Rigid PVC (SR-PVC)` under the `Plastic` materials:

> http://www.awcwire.com/insulation-materials.aspx

See sub-heading `UL Style 1007, CSA TR-64` under `Polyvinylchloride (PVC) Insulated UL/CSA Hook-Up Wire`:

> http://www.standard-wire.com/downloads/swc_catalog.pdf

See `PolyVinyl Chloride (PVC)` under the `Thermoplastic` heading:

> http://www.usawire-cable.com/pdfs/wire%20knowledge.pdf

Comment: Useful solutions in low-risk-of-damage may also include Silicone (150 to 250 deg C rated are most common) or glassfiber reinforced Silicone (200 to 350 deg C most common) - The latter is better suited for rough or sharp terrain, sometimes usually even better than PVC. But then, Teflon itself is also very soft. Might be good to include that in the advice; if there's sharp edges or a lot of rough abrasion that won't always do. (light abrasion should be fine as Teflon is slick as hell, but requires testing).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I bought some silicone cable which should endure temps from -80 celsius to 260 celsius:)